# Speed Up While loop In php

Tags: php, while-loop, memcached, each

right the problem is a smallish one but hope someone can help.
Basically we use memcache to cache some of our mysql queries and then store the results in an array for memcache. Then when the query runs again it grabs the array results from memcache and processes the results like normal.
So the code looks like this.

```
$query = "SELECT x,y,z FROM a WHERE b = 3";
$result = mysql_query_run($query,'memcache_name');
while($row = mysql_mem_fetch_array($result,'memcache_name')) {

 //do processing

}
```

mysql_query_run basically just either runs the query or returns the array from memcache.
The mysql_mem_fetch_array either processes the results from mysql or transverses the array.

The transversing part uses this code.

```
if(is_array($result)) {
            $return = current($result);
            //get the current result - based on the internal pointer
            next($result);//increment pointed
            return $return;//return result
        }
        else {

            //mysql result tab
            //so get the array from the mysql_fetch_array
            $array = mysql_fetch_array($result);

            if(is_array($MEMCACHE_SERVER_RESULTS[$memcache])==false) {
                //if there is no results then just set the results as array
                $MEMCACHE_SERVER_RESULTS[$memcache] = array();
            }
            //push the array onto the end of the current array - from memcache

            //if there are some results then push them on
            if($single_row == 1) {
                //only one row so just combine the 2 steps and store
                array_push($MEMCACHE_SERVER_RESULTS[$memcache],$array);
                $MEMCACHE_SERVER->set($memcache, $MEMCACHE_SERVER_RESULTS[$memcache],0,$memcache_time);
            }
            else if($array!==false) {

                array_push($MEMCACHE_SERVER_RESULTS[$memcache],$array);
                //and set it
            }
            else {
                //set the memcache to the array that it has been making.
                $MEMCACHE_SERVER->set($memcache, $MEMCACHE_SERVER_RESULTS[$memcache],0,$memcache_time);
            }

            //return array
            return $array;

        }
```

The problem is the current and next commands - in large arrays (which are very rare) it causes some hanging. 
Currently we are in php version 5.1.6 and we are going to 5.3 will the problem be solved?
Or is there a better way to handle the array?
Thanks for your help.
Richard

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> in large arrays (which are very rare) it causes some hanging.

Easy. Just avoid storing large arrays in memcache.

Comment: To be honest with you, that's a good answer - and one that I might consider doing. Thanks! - Just takes a different perspective!
(I feel like a fish has been slapped across my face!)

Comment: You know, memcache is ALREADY such an array, made exactly for that purpose. And with access to it's elements at blazing speed. why do you want to make it slower byt storing large blobs of data and moving it to anf fro - a thing that's puzzling me.

Answer (score 1):

If you do:

```
if (is_array($result)) {
  $return = each($result); //get the current result and advance the array pointer
  return $return['value']; //return result
} else // ...and so on
```

...is it any better?

Comment: ...and what's wrong with this? By all means downvote me if you have a good reason, but please have the courtesy to explain why...

Comment: Sorry I didn't downvote you - I don't know who did.
In answer though I have tried it and the webgrind software says no - strangely it is slower!
Thanks though for adding it to the mix.
If anything it's useful for people to know the full story - upvote!

Comment: @RichardHousham PHP can be odd like that, when a single function does the job of two, you would have thought it would be quicker, but sometimes it's not... I guess it's related to the internal implementations. I think that Col.Shrapnels answer is probably *the* answer, if you're doing queries that return a very large result set, you probably shouldn't cache them because the result is (more) likely to change between queries, and it will eat memory. one thing I would say - you could probably make this more efficient by using `mysql_fetch_assoc` or `mysql_fetch_row` over `mysql_fetch_array`.

Comment: You took this question literally, but missed it's meaning by a mile. To let you know, all this silly stuff about "how to iterate an array" have nothing to do with performance. Only noobs who have not a bit of practical experience of the matter, do believe that a syntax construct may affect anything.

Comment: @Col.Shrapnel Well you say that, but just try timing the difference between `foreach` and `while (list($var1,$var2) = each())`. I know it doesn't make a difference unless you have either huge numbers of subjects or huge subjects, and that `premature optimisation is the root of all evil`, but when people ask questions about efficiency generally what they want is answers about efficiency, however small the difference may be in practice...

Comment: they ask for real efficiency, not s bunch of silly delusions and superstitions.

Comment: Thanks for the input from both of you it's really nice to get such good feedback from nice people, especially when you have been looking over this for weeks - sometimes another persons perspective is all that is needed.